# How filter from results of group.limit

Tags: solr, filter

I have a problem with solr.
First I group.main = true and group.limit = 1 then I have results, how could I filter from results match my conditions (example : from results (A) of group.limit = 1, I want to filter from A to get results (B)).
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent support for referencing previous groups when using [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) in Solr, but you can achieve the same feature by re-using the query that generates the first query and appending the new clause.

```
group.query=fieldA:value&group.query=fieldA:value AND fieldB:value
```

This will give you two grouped entries in the response, one for where fieldA has a value, and one where fieldA and fieldB has a specific value.

If you're talking about more general filtering after presenting a grouped result, issuing a query with `q=field:value` is enough.